# Why the working code for check chekboxes does not work in the template?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, checkboxlist

I have work with inbox messages. I use this [template](http://demo.interface.club/limitless/layout_1/LTR/default/mail_list.html) for example inbox. And in that inbox have HTML button code with check all messages checkbox:

```
<div class="btn-group navbar-btn">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-icon btn-checkbox-all">
      <input type="checkbox" onClick="selectAll(this)" class="styled">
   </button>
</div>
```

And in div block inside table have message list:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-inbox">
        <tbody data-link="row" class="rowlink">
            <tr class="unread">
                <td class="table-inbox-checkbox rowlink-skip">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="styled" name="messages[]">
                </td>
                <td class="table-inbox-message">
                    <span class="table-inbox-subject">Subject 1</span>
                    <span class="table-inbox-preview">Message text 1</span>
                </td>
                <td class="table-inbox-time">
                    11:09 pm
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="unread">
                <td class="table-inbox-checkbox rowlink-skip">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="styled" name="messages[]">
                </td>
                <td class="table-inbox-message">
                    <span class="table-inbox-subject">Subject 2</span>
                    <span class="table-inbox-preview">Message text 2</span>
                </td>
                <td class="table-inbox-time">
                    09:09 pm
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I have simple javascript code for check all checkboxes:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function selectAll(source) {
        checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('messages[]');
        for(var i in checkboxes)
            checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
    }
</script>
```

Javascript code not work for check messages inside of table. Why not work code? But In sample code work for check:

```html
<input type="checkbox" onClick="selectAll(this)" />Select All
<ul>
 <li><input type="checkbox" name="messages[]" value="red" />Red</li>
 <li><input type="checkbox" name="messages[]" value="blue" />Blue</li>
 <li><input type="checkbox" name="messages[]" value="green" />Green</li>
 <li><input type="checkbox" name="messages[]" value="black" />Black</li>
</ul>

<script language="JavaScript">
 function selectAll(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('messages[]');
  for(var i in checkboxes)
   checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
 }
</script>
```

#### Downloads

You can download and see inbox template [here](http://mahorat.org/checkbox.rar)

And how I can send checked checkboxes values using POST method send to php file?

Comment: If I swap the html, it seems to work. It also seems to work in that reproduction: https://jsfiddle.net/caja3ezd/

Comment: will you please check this pen ? https://codepen.io/mrsafari/pen/MrqzvK    I believe that your first code is correct and fully working.

Comment: Yes work I seen your code, But it not work in fully html template @Axnyff. You seen my using template?

Comment: Checking not work in full HTML template code

Comment: Can you re-create a non-working jsfiddle please? It works for us when we are using your html and js

Comment: @MaxNet I don't see any click event for the checkbox in that site. check to see if any on click event binds for the (Select All) checkbox.

Comment: @Axnyff its not working in his template.

Comment: Now I will update my question

Comment: Please download and see html code in template